# Force value verification with Numeric Enum

Tags: javascript, typescript

Shouldn't I receive a warning for this:

```js
enum Animals {
    CAT = 1, DOG, SNAKE
}


interface AnimalsTest {
    animalKind: Animals.CAT | Animals.DOG | Animals.SNAKE
}

let myAnimal: AnimalsTest = {animalKind: 4};
```

I expect to restrict a property number with this kind of logic, but it's not working. 
Could I change it and use enums for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number` is assignable to enum (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26362) and there's no way to create a type from enum values. If you need this functionality, an object with a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) would be a better option:

```
const Animals = <const>{
    CAT: 1,
    DOG: 2
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

interface AnimalsTest {
    animalKind: Values<typeof Animals>
}

let a: AnimalsTest = {animalKind: Animals.DOG}; // ok
let b: AnimalsTest = {animalKind: 2}; // ok too
let c: AnimalsTest = {animalKind: 42}; // not ok
```